# Why was this question closed? Is it unpopular, or am I missing something?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

This is the question I am referring to:

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9293/proposal-dont-show-posters-name-until-upvote-downvote

I suspect that this question was closed because it was an unpopular suggestion. Whilst I agree that the suggestion is flawed, I don't see any problems with the question as it stands, and can't think of any valid reason for it to be closed.

As well as the fact that the question $\textit{was}$ closed, from what I can see, no-one that voted to close left any comment indicating why they were doing so. Considering that several questions have been posted in meta recently asking people to leave comments when closing a question, I was surprised to see this, because if I can't see a valid reason for closure, I doubt that the OP can, which may lead them to suspect that the question was closed because it was unpopular. Whether or not this is true, I imagine that it would be fairly discouraging for a new user.

Comment: I've cast the last re-open vote. While I disagree with the proposal, I think the question should not be closed only because the majority disagrees with the proposal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I voted to close partly because the motivation (the first paragraph) was fallacious. Furthermore, e.g. robjohn's comment said all there was to be said, IMO. There was not much to be added to the observations made in the comments. So a close vote from my part further indicated that I thought the thread was "finished", even though there weren't any answers.

Comment: Thank's for answering! but I can't help but feel that feeling like a question is "finished" isn't a good reason for closing. We don't good questions when they've been answered satisfactorily, or if they haven't been answered for a long time. Further, what if it's not finished? By closing the question, you make it impossible for anyone else to contribute without re-opening the question. I understand your reasons, but I suppose that I just disagree.

Comment: You're probably right, it's not for me to decide whether or not a thread is to be considered finished. I'll be more thoughtful in the future.